# Failed to resolve: android.arch.persistence.room:runtime: 1.0.0-alpha1

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

I am unable to compile the following **`gradle`** :-

```
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime: 1.0.0-alpha1'
```

Error Message :-

```
Error:(26, 13) Failed to resolve: android.arch.persistence.room:runtime: 1.0.0-alpha1
```

Show in File Show in Project Structure `dialog`

It would be of help if somebody could loop in and help me here!!

Comment: `allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}`

Answer (score 5):

Library has a release version, update your gradle:

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

More: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components.html

Comment: This also did not work, it worked for me after upgrading my gradle build version to 3.0.0 from 2.2.0.

Comment: Ok, just update Gradle version, Gradle plugin and the last library version.

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this question is a bit old and that the current version of Room as of today is 1.1.1, but I think that your issue was actually due to the space between the last colon (:) after "runtime" and before the version (in this case, 1.0.0-alpha1).

For example, rather than `'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime: 1.0.0-alpha1'` it should read `'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1'`